# Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.XdbUnavailableException Message: xDB unavailable

Tags: xdb, mongodb

I am trying to map Sitecore 9.1 with MongoDB.I have Provided all required settings but still getting an exception.

```
Message: xDB unavailable
Source: Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect
 at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.ExecuteWithExceptionHandling[T](Func`2 func)
 at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.Monitor[T](OperationPerformanceMonitorBase monitor, Func`1 operation)
 at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Dictionaries.XConnectDeviceDictionary.LoadAs[T](Object key)
 at Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.AverageCounterExtensions.MeasureMilliseconds[T](AverageCounter counter, Func`1 func)
 at Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.ReferenceDataDictionary`2.Get(TKey key, LookupStrategy strategy)
 at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.EnsureDevice.LoadDevice(Guid deviceId)

Nested Exception

Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: {
"Message": "Operation failed: One or more dependencies failed",
"ExceptionMessage": "One or more dependencies failed",
"ExceptionType": "Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.DependencyFailedException",
"StackTrace": null,
"InnerException": {
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Keyword not supported: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/sc91instance2_collection?retrywrites'.",
  "ExceptionType": "System.ArgumentException",
  "StackTrace": "   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder.GetIndex(String keyword)\r\n
}
```

My Mongo Db connectionstrings are:

```
<add name="session" connectionString="mongodb://localhost:27017/sc91instance2_session"/> 
  <add name="collection" connectionString="mongodb://localhost:27017/sc91instance2_collection?retryWrites=true"/>
```

Please help me if anyone faced similar issue or anyone has some experience regrading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the nested error message, it looks like your connection string has an invalid format. Your exception reads:

```
"ExceptionMessage": "Keyword not supported: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/sc91instance2_collection?retrywrites'.",
```

Have you tried without the 'retrywrites' portion in your connection string?

Comment: Yes, it throws similar exception in that case also.  These connectionstrings work fine in another instance.

Comment: Similar, but different? What is the error when you eliminate his portion? The nested exception is likely important to debug the issue